# Update html and css on multiple sites using external database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, database

I need to be able to add specific HTML and CSS dynamically to banners used for people that donate to a charity I work with.  The credits will be displayed across multiple partner sites. The problem is that the charity's banner can change quite often, given different events that take place. Some partners require specific text type, and other CSS styling. Now this could be done manually, by hard coding each page. But updating so many sites for every event gets difficult.

The idea I had:

Sort each partner's needs light banner/dark banner, light/dark text, link color, etc. into one database on the charity's server.

Then, have each partner add an empty

```
<div id="charityDiv">
    <img src="">
    <a href=""></a>
</div>
```

and some form of unique javascript token that would be used to reference the external database.

Then, when the page is loaded the database can be referenced, and the proper images, text, and CSS would be displayed.

---

Does anyone know of a better way to do what I am trying to do?
Does anyone have a good tutorial or example to start research on this?

Comment: What server side software are you using?  You could just add the banner code with a simple database look-up when serving the page.  This could be done completely without Javascript.

Comment: that is the beauty of css. You might get away with css by id in a directory. Prefix your banner with a unique stylename and then add styles per the prefix. I would normally recommend images in this case, but it sounds like you want one banner with unique styling for each client

Comment: Response:

The banners are displayed on a lot of sites.  Most are a standard lamp, but a few are iis/mssql.  The larger issue with this is access.  Most partners are want to display a banner on their site after making a donation, but to open their code for a lookup or some server side scripting isn't an option.  A small snippet of js with a container <div> seemed a smaller footprint.

Comment: Response:
Exactly, the styling / text can be unique for each partner.  I wish it were as simple as them just adding [url to img directory on charity's server] logoDark.png *or* logoLight.png to their code, once, and never have to worry about it again.  Only having to update the img files and keeping their names the same

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an iframe on each of the partner sites. This way the update is centralised with the updates on the partner sites taking care of themselves once the data changes.

Comment: Response:  That was my *first* thought as well.  I was told that more than one of the partners took issue with the idea.  One who I had a relationship with said, their seoperson apparently had an issue and wanted the "backlink credit"  That generally isn't my thing, I was just requested to find another way.  :(